# Want to create Java EE project in Java SE eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have Eclipse Indigo for Java SE and I have Tomcat in Ubuntu. I would like to develop a Java EE application, using Servlet and JSP.

My Eclipse doesn't include Java EE support. Can I add this somehow?  If yes, any extra tool or plugin I need to install or download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You'll need to use a server like Tomcat to run your application anyway.  (Which you have already.)  It comes with <tomcat install>/lib/servlet-api.jar.  Just include this in your classpath when developing so the code compiles.

Since Tomcat doesn't support the full Java EE spec, it only gives you the Servlet APIs. But that is enough for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Under which folder i can find this jar.I searched inside tomcat folder didn't get any :(

Comment: Edited my post to add this info and because my post was originally confusing!

Comment: I think Jsp will also work here as Jsp internally is servlet only, right ?

Comment: You don't need to compile a JSP in your IDE. (I actually turn off JSP validation in my IDE.)  It will get compiled when you run it in Tomcat.  Note that good current JSPs don't have Java code in them anyway.  Just scriptlets.

Comment: ok i will do it j2ee eclipse.But can you tell me how to run php file from apache.I have apache2 in ubuntu.When i am typing http://localhost, it is whoing it work.when shud i keep my php file to be run by apache.